# How can I update a specific record in a sql database based on a selection made in a dropdown select box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Ok, I have spent days on this, and I am out of my depth. I admit I am completely new to sql, jquery, and ajax. I apologize in advance for this.

I am trying to build an application where an admin can see a users performance over time, averaging the last 2 weeks of input scores. Using a dropdown box a member should be selected from the DB (this part seems to work), then a form below can be filled out and an "update" button pressed to update the record in the DB (this is completely broken).

The select box is populated from the DB with ajax, and I can return values from the selection with an onchange function, but when I try to then update the database with my form, nothing is updated.

The insert button and associated code work properly, and information is stored correctly in the DB. (I will break the data off into more accurate tables when I have the code correct as I did not want to deal with joins and multiple tables while struggling.)

When selecting a name from the select menu $_POST['memberID'] shows the correct number.

Once information is entered into the form and "update" is pressed, $_POST['memberID'] is blank and the DB is not updated.

Controller.php:

```
<?php require 'php/dbconnect.php';
$records = array();
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    switch (true) {
        case isset($_POST['insert']):
            if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['designation'], $_POST['rank'], $_POST['currentScore'])) {
                // The following trim functions followed by !empty ensures that a series of spaces is not accepted from users as input.
                $name = trim($_POST['name']);
                $designation = trim($_POST['designation']);
                $rank = trim($_POST['rank']);
                $currentScore = trim($_POST['currentScore']);

                if(!empty($name) && !empty($designation) && !empty($rank) && !empty($currentScore)) {

                    $insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO members (name, designation, rank, currentScore) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
                    $insert->bind_param('ssii' , $name, $designation, $rank, $currentScore);

                    if($insert->execute()) {
                        $insert->free(); //Remove Query Data from memory since it is no longer needed.
                        header('location: index.php');
                        die();
                    }
                }
            }
        break;

        case isset($_POST['update']):
            $name = trim($_POST['name']);
            if(!empty($name)) {
            $update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE members SET name = ? WHERE '$memberID'");
            $update->bind_param('s', $name);
                if($update->execute()) {
                        header('location: index.php');
                        die();
                    }
            }
        break;

//      case isset($_POST['delete']):
//          // Delete statement goes here
//      break;
//      else 
    }
}
if($results = $conn->query("SELECT *, ((previousScore + currentScore) / 2) AS avgScore FROM members")) {
    if($results->num_rows) {
        while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
            $records[] = $row; //Appending value to array
        }
        $results->free();
    }
}
?>
```

Index.php:

```
<?php include 'header.php' ?>
     <?php if(!count($records)) {
        echo 'No Records' ;
     } else {
     ?>
    <form id="memberSelect" method="post">
        <select name="memberID" id="members" onchange="change()">
            <!-- Populated with function members in footer.php -->
        </select>
    </form>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Designation</th>
                    <th>Rank</th>
                    <th>Previous Score</th>
                    <th>Current Score</th>
                    <th>Average Score</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                foreach($records as $r) {
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo escape($r->name); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo escape($r->designation); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo escape($r->rank); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo escape($r->previousScore); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo escape($r->currentScore); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo escape($r->avgScore); ?></td>
                    <!-- Remember when putting data in that current score needs to be moved to previous score's
                    position and the NEW score will take the place of current score(which will be the old score until updated) -->
                </tr>
                <?php 
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

    <hr>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="name">Member name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="designation">Designation</label>
            <input type="text" name="designation" id="designation" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="rank">Rank</label>
            <input type="text" name="rank" id="charLevel" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="currentScore">Current Score</label>
            <input type="text" name="currentScore" id="currentScore" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div id="submit">
            <!-- Add a comment section to be input into DB -->
            <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Insert">
            <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
            <!-- <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php //echo $?>"> -->
        </div>
    </form>
<?php include 'footer.php' ?>
```

Footer.php:

```
</div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script>
            //How do you explain something you barely understand? The following function uses JQUERY
            //json, and ajax to fill a select dropdown with items populated from a linked database.
            //See the jsonData.php for the json data being referenced here, it is imperitive to the operation of
            //this function that json data be available.
            function members(){
                $('#members').empty();//Removes all content of the associated ID 'members' to ensure a clean default value
                $('#members').append("<option>Loading</option>");//fill them with a default message
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"php/jsonData.php",//the location of the json data, for this it is required to be in its own file
                    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(records){ //only fires if the json data is found
                        $('#members').empty();//If everything is ok, removes previous default value
                        $('#members').append("<option value='0'>--Select Member--</option>");
                        $.each(records,function(i,memberID){//Uses a foreach loop to fire a function for every memberID, assigning the value to i
                            $('#members').append('<option value="'+ records[i].memberID +'">'+ records[i].name +'</option>');
                            //^ The workhorse. Grabs the select value by the ID, appends the option value by looking within the records array
                            //(which is defined and assigned values in the jsonData.php file) and assigns the member id as the value and the 'name'
                            //as the option. This populates the dropdown with the names and gives them the value 'memberID' from the database.
                        });
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                     }
                });
            }
            $(document).ready(function(){
                members();
            });
        </script>
        <script>
            function change(){
                $('#memberSelect').submit();//Submits the page to the server when called
            }
        </script>

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
            function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
            e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
            e.src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
            ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X','auto');ga('send','pageview');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you really cant narrow it down some?

Comment: When ever I see a question like this, I always feel like shouting break it down in two separate problems and solve them individually. You have two problems get your form working properly (don't need mysql for that). Then you have to figure out how to updat ea mysql row based on some php variable. Javascript and html has nothing to do wtih that.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I appreciate them, and I will continue trying to figure this out. My problem is that I am having trouble figuring out what is going wrong, which will just take time for me to figure out.

@e4c5 I feel like shouting as well. It has been several days, and I know these are basic level issues.

Comment: Programming is like eating an elephant you need to do one tiny problem at a time and the big problem get's solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line of the Update Block:

```
$update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE members SET name = ? WHERE '$memberID'");
```

I am assuming the primary key of your member table is: `member_id`

Then this code will be:

```
$update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE members SET name = ? WHERE member_id = ?");
$update->bind_param('si', $name, $memberID);
```

Try this. Hope it helps.

Comment: I had several problems, of which this was one. This code works perfectly and helped me so much. Thank you!